# error booting ubuntu,xubuntu installation on virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, virtualbox, xubuntu

i have tried to install ubuntu 14.04.1 on my virtualbox, after I inserted the path to my iso image, I started the machine, but i always get this:

[image: Error]

I also tried with xubuntu.

I have windows 8.1, and my virtual box version is 4.3.16

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to change the iso file..??

Comment: yes, i got the same result

Comment: Did some one solve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the ISO/Image on a bootable medium (disk or flash drive) then select the medium when booting up the Virtual Box, and see if it takes it that way.

How much memory and space have you dedicated to the machine, and how much do you have on your hard disk and windows partition? Try a smaller os, such as puppy linux, knoppix, or DSL(-n), and see if it reads from there, or, alternatively, remove and reinstall Virtual box, and make sure the Architecture is correct (amd64/x86) based on your cpu. In addition, make sure that when you are setting up the virtual machine that you have the right OS selected when doing so that the OS's architecture is correct (for instance, if you have a 32 bit cpu architecture then you want a 32 bit ubuntu os, or alternatively, if you have a 64 bit cpu architecture then you want a 64 bit ubuntu os. Also the amount of ram allocated affects this, and you should use 32 bit for machines with less than 2 gb of RAM dedicated)